# Review queue for non-complying questions

Tags: feature-request, review, question-restrictions

Currently there are a couple of restrictions that apply to posting / editing questions, such as that "problem" may not appear in the title (I briefly looked for others, but couldn't find them).

I'm specifically referring to restrictions that were put into place some time after the site was established, thus there are posts that don't comply.

I suggest we add a review queue for these questions.

This queue should:

- Presumably tell you what's wrong (e.g. "'problem' in the title").
- Have an option for voting to close the post (thus it will have to be for 3k+ users, and only accessible when you have close votes?).
- Possibly have a "Leave it" option for those cases when there's nothing else wrong and "problem" isn't a problem (e.g. "halting problem"). Once a few users select this option for the same post, it will be removed from the queue.

The numbers in this queue would be fairly static (since new questions not complying can't get posted, and adding restrictions are presumably somewhat rare).

Two thoughts:

- Perhaps this queue should be temporary - only have it be visible after a new restriction has been added and disappear once all the questions have been processed.
- Perhaps have the queue also contain other questions requiring changes, such as those with tags that should be burninated.

Comment: But what pr0blem would this solve? Those questions are arguably easy to find through search. Also, not *every* question containing "problem" need a fix.

Comment: As far as I know non complying questions also seem to be generatable by a complying questions being suggested edited to non complying;  the example I'm thinking of is when someone puts nonsense into their question to get it past a quality filter and then someone else edits the nonsense out

Comment: the fact that these posts exist isn't a problem.  And when someone needs to edit the posts, they will be corrected to comply with current rules, or they won't be edited.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That's the problem - the reviewer might get overwhelmed trying to fix the now-issue (I know I have). If we could have a queue for people prepared to deal with these problems, we could cut down on that considerably,

Comment: @RichardTingle Those are not the kind of restrictions I'm referring to - you can't edit "problem" into the title.

Comment: @probablyPekka The restrictions are in place, presumably, to prevent low quality content. Many of these questions probably aren't particularly good otherwise either. So, having a queue with mostly low quality content can't be a bad thing, can it (and needs little motivation, I hope)? And not all of them may be bad, but the restriction is still there - any future edit will have to remove it in anyway, and forcing this somewhat trivial removal into a queue isn't that bad - the benefit is the other questions.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Most of my comment @ probablyPekka applies to your comment as well.

Comment: OK, but suppose the queue sends you into edit mode, and for that one instance, you decide the word "problem" is in there rightly. You make  a couple of other edits in the question - but now you can't save them because of the word "problem" in the title! The "problem" filter has always been a... disputed idea. That's dislike the idea of basing a review queue on it. Still, building review queues based on indicators of low quality is a perfectly fine idea in general, and the future I suppose

Comment: @probablyPekka But, if not removing "problem", you won't be able to edit the question, with or without the queue. If the problem is "problem", and you decide to edit the question, you should know to remove it (perhaps in the form of "this is what's wrong" notification to start). I agree some questions would be better off with "problem" in the title, but this request is not about discussing the "problem" filter. Perhaps we should have a "Leave it" option for when the question's only problem is something that's not a problem (such as some cases of "problem").

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a great idea. It should be easy to write this in such a way as to capture additional questions whenever the rules on acceptability change, hence it may not need to be a short-term list. I guess it depends on how often the rules are being fiddled.

This feature would encourage consistency - no reason for old questions to exist on the site that break the rules that new users must follow. New users often complain when they are subjected to rules that they clearly see did not apply to other questions in the past.

Comment: I'm not sure about the users often complaining about that. The main thing I've seen is referencing old now-off-topic questions as justification for on-topic-ness, which doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @Dukeling It's more of a general observation that when we leave old questions about that violate some aspect of today's rules, it grates against new users. But I agree, it's mostly the off-topic questions that provide the most grief.